Imperva Websocket connect
Excuse me, for a week I have not been able to connect to secureSphere to activate websocket for my website which uses imperva.
I need help please
I tried to connect to secureSphere https://mywebsit.com:8443 but it doesn't work.
How to made?
I am using imperva service.thanks
